# Haskell Int -> Word64 conversion

Tags: haskell, integer

This should be pretty simple. I have an Int and I want to convert it to a Word64. It can never be less than 0. I don't mind if it has error checking or not. It seems I can do the opposite conversion using fromIntegral, but I can't find the inverse function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well,

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

should be perfectly capable of converting from `Int` to `Word64` since `Int` is an instance of `Integral` and `Word64` is an instance of `Num`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, I don't know why I didn't think of that.